# jQuery : select multiple ID's and an ID in a variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want something like this :

```
$('.iclickable').click(function(){

var clickedId=  '#' + $(this).attr("id") + ' *';

$(document).click(function(e){
  if($(e.target).is('#submenu , #submenu *', clickedId))
  return;
});

});
```

But it doesn't work.How can i do that ?
I want select 2 ID's and a variable that contains an element's ID
and all of it's children

The html :

```
<div id= "submenu">
  //several Div's
</div>

<div class="iclickable" id= "iclickable1">
  //several Div's
</div>
<div class="iclickable" id= "iclickable2">
  //several Div's
</div>
<div class="iclickable" id= "iclickable3">
  //several Div's
</div>
```

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish with this code? Also, post the accompanying HTML.

Comment: code provided makes very little sense so there isn't much way for us to know what you are trying to do

Comment: still not clear what you are trying to acheive. Please put more effort into explaining issues in more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see doing this is to break it up into chunks separated with `OR`

```
if($(e.target).is('#submenu') || $(e.target).is('#submenu *') || $(e.target).is(clickedId)) {
  return;
}
```